# Referencing bootstrap class in JQuery for ASP generated HTML

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, vbscript, asp-classic

My page uses ASP (VBScript) to generate a div with bootstrap class 'alert' upon successful SQL submission.  What I want to happen is this - Once a user submits the form and the alert div appears, then they click on the first input field of the form, I want the alert div to disappear.  I have a feeling the issue lies with:

A.) Referencing a div generated by ASP in JQuery
B.) Referencing a div with multiple bootstrap classes
C.) Maybe I'm breaking some golden rule that everyone knows and I don't.

Any help would be much appreciated.  Code is below:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

$(function(){
$("qName").click(function(){
    $(".alert").hide();
});
});

</script>

</head>
<body>
<!-- #include virtual="/navbar.asp" -->
<section>
    <div class='container'>
        <div class='row well well-lg'>
            <% 
                If intStatus = 1 Then
                    Response.Write("<div class='alert alert-success'><h3 class='text-center'>Entry Successful!</h3></div>")
                ElseIf intStatus = 2 Then
                    Response.Write("<div class='alert alert-warning'><h3 class='text-center'>This query name already exists! Would you like to update the existing entry?</h3></div>")
                End If  
            %>
            <div class='text-center'>
                <h3>SQL Query Entry</h3>
                <i>Add SQL statements to be used by the Query Search Web Tool.</i><br>
            </div><br>
            <form method="post" action="/webtools/queryadd.asp" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="reportform">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label class="control-label col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-3" for="qName">Query Name: </label>
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="qName" name="qName" placeholder="Enter Query Name (60 char max)" <% If intStatus = 0 Then %>value="<%=Request.form("qName") %>"<% End If %> maxlength="60" required>
                    </div>
...........................................
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `#` to reference an element by it's ID

`$("qName").click(function(){`

should be

`$("#qName").click(function(){`

Comment: Syntax...the bane of my existence.  Thank you @SearchAndResQ